# How can you observe changes on every item in a model in Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a model called 'matter_has_user', on a particular page, i will have some number of items of this type.  Each of these will be store objects and will have a value called bill_alert which will be connected to a checkbox.  So i need to watch all of these checkboxes and when a change occurs, i need to issue a save to the api.

So how can you go about this?   Can you set up observers on a certain property for each item of a particular type?  How can I set up listeners on each of these checkboxes to fire a specific action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model is a collection of these objects, you can set up an observer on each of them like this:

```
myObserver: function(){
  //do something
}).observes('model.@each.bill_alert')
```

[docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That's just what i was looking for.  One question i had further, after this observer fires and i am in the function, how do i access the store objects that was clicked.  When the checkbox is clicked, i would like to be able to access the specific store object that it is associated with and save it to the api after changing the value of bill_alert.

Comment: One thought that springs to mind is that you could utilize the `isDirty` property of an Ember store object. e.g. `myObject.get('isDirty')` will evaluate to `true` if that object has been changed since the last time it was saved

Comment: yeah, that would be easy enough.  i suppose the confusion i am having is that when the observer fires, it seems the scope that i am in is the scope of the controller.  I would have hoped that i would be in the scope of the clicked item.

myObserver: function(item){
    // item seems to be controller scope
}.ovserves('model.@each.bill_alert')

Comment: Perhaps what you want is to have each item in your list represented by an Ember component. That way instead of observing from the controller each component can observe the model that is specific to it